# Export Visio Macros to Visio COM-Add-in

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vba, visio, comaddin

I have written some Makros and Functions in VB all code works fine behind my Document.
To save my code and make it available to other users I want to create a COM-add-in for VIsio.
So i bought Visual Studio 2008 and I want to import my code to it.

Is it possible to include my exported .cls file to my Visual Studio COM-Add-on Projekt?

Answer (score 0):

Classes in Visual Studio are the same plain text files with a .cs extension (as opposed to cls), so you could create a new class in your project, and copy over your code from VBA.